# Help regarding occasional Ubuntu 20.04 crash

Tags: kernel

I have occasional crashes of my Ubuntu 20.04 on a Shuttle XPC Cube SH87R with 32 GB Kingston DDR3-1600 RAM, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER GPU, 2 x Toshiba 3 TB HDD in an mdadm software RAID 1 mirror and LVM, one 256 GB SSD with 32GB used as swap.

I use latest Nvidia proprietary Linux driver 515.65.01 with DKMS, and the system if fully updated with latest updates.

I have run multiple extensive memtest86+ memory testing going through multiple full passes with no errors reported.

The crash happens infrequently - maybe once a month or two - and to diagnose the problem i have set up Kernel dumps to /var/crash. But I am not sure how to use the crash information, which is as follows.

```
ls -al /var/crash 
total 48 
drwxrwsrwt  3 root whoopsie  4096 Aug 25 22:26 . 
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root      4096 Nov  4  2021 .. 
drwxr-sr-x  2 root whoopsie  4096 Aug 25 22:24 202208252224
-rw-r--r--  1 root whoopsie   412 Aug 28 09:29 kexec_cmd
-rw-r-----  1 root whoopsie 30651 Aug 25 22:26 linux-image-5.4.0-125-generic-202208252224.crash

ls -al /var/crash/whoopsie/
total 1315908
drwxr-sr-x 2 root whoopsie       4096 Aug 25 22:24 .
drwxrwsrwt 3 root whoopsie       4096 Aug 25 22:26 ..
-rw------- 1 root whoopsie      78133 Aug 25 22:24 dmesg.202208252224
-rw------- 1 root whoopsie 1347392784 Aug 25 22:24 dump.202208252224
```

The contents of the dmesg file just prior to the crash is as follows:

```
[ 3528.253961] TCP: br0: Driver has suspect GRO implementation, TCP performance may be compromised.
[ 5154.707563] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 4: ba00000058000402
[ 5154.716109] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 10:<ffffffffbc813ebc> {filemap_map_pages+0x2dc/0x380}
[ 5154.725475] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC ff0bc5dd3d3 
[ 5154.730364] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1661458894 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 28
[ 5154.739238] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'
[ 5154.746078] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check: Processor context corrupt
[ 5154.753078] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal machine check
```

Suggestions would be appreciated.

---

Response to comments:

I am not sure incorrect BIOS setting is the culprit, since it has been running stable with the present BIOS setting for years, 24/7.  The BIOS options are somewhat basic. I can't change CPU voltage.  I could lower the RAM frequency but metest86+ shows no errors.  I wonder if the mce exception refers to a cache memory bank or RAM ?   If it is cache, then I guess the CPU is getting tired - after all it is a PC from 2013 who has been running nonstop, with only changing cmos battery and replacing the mirrored disks through mdadm.  I currently is leaning towards microcode or CPU voltage.  I did replace the original 300w power supply with a 500w when I put in the Nvidia 1660, which use 125W max and the cpu is rated 84 W.  I guess I could experiment to put in the old power supply and see if CPU voltage increase above current 1.0 value.  But 300w is probably slightly marginal, but for testing with little GPU power it would give a hint I guess.  I can get a new 500w supply still for about 90$.

Comment: It says `Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii'` why not include it?

Comment: I did not have mcelog utility when I wrote it.  And there was no mcelog file in /var/log.  I have since downloaded and compile mcelog and used the dmesg as input but that pretty much showed the same thing altough a little more pretty printed.

Comment: I have decided to roll back the intel microcode to previous version.  It appears the present version was released in may 2022, which correlates approximately with the appearance of the problem. I will monitor the problem and see if it helps.  I am still interested in anyone who can explain in more detail the meanin of the MCE error messages - i.e. cache etc.

Comment: FWIW I think I have found a description of the MCE 5 error on intel web site and it appears the error message mean "Internal Parity Error".  It does not make me much wiser regarding which component was at fault, but since it is internal, it would appear that it is in some CPU subsystem, which could be a subtle bug in the new microcode leading to occasional crash.  I guess I will know in a month or two if the problem is related to the new microcode, after rollback to previous version.